# Remove Any in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I was wondering if this piece of code could be better:

```cs
return Collection.Any(x => x.Type.Equals(type))
    ? Collection.Single(x => x.Type.Equals(type)).SomeThingAsANumber
    : 0;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"

Comment: A smaller version as posted below :)

Comment: Better is to remove that. It  has worst performance and two enumerations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-5.0) with [Null coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operator

```
return Collection.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(type))?.SomeThingAsANumber ?? 0
```

To avoid null reference exception, I used null [conditional operator(?.)](https://thedotnetguide.com/null-conditional-operator-in-csharp/)

---

Your query iterate twice with same condition,

```
return Collection.Any(x => x.Type.Equals(type))  //Iterate till the condition satisfies and return true or false
    ? Collection.Single(x => x.Type.Equals(type)).SomeThingAsANumber // Iterate same number of times and return Single record. 
    : 0; //Otherwise return 0
```

In above solution, **we reduced its time complexity by half** as my solution iterate only once.

```
//Return expected number if record found or Null if condition fails.
return Collection.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(type))?.SomeThingAsANumber   
?? 0 //Null coalescing operator helps to return 0 if left side Linq returns null
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in a comment from @Sajid you can use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.SingleOrDefault()`. As you can guess they behave almost the same with the major difference being that `.SingleOrDefault()` throws and exception in case it finds more than one match. If this is what you want to do intentionally then I suggest using the above code in a `try-catch` block. If you are sure that there will be no more than one match (or you don't care if there is) you better use `.FristOrDefault()` - it is more readable in this situation and can perform a lot better in certain cases (`.FristOrDefault()` iterates until it finds the first match and `.SingleOrDefault()` iterates over the whole collection in order to make sure there is no duplicate that matches the given criteria).